# Danger in terminating process using Manager().Queue()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) are clear that terminating a process while it is using a `multiprocessing.Queue` can result in corruption of the queue. What is not clear is if the same limitation applies to a [`Manager().Queue()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Queue). Because the manager runs in a separate process, I can imagine it recovering from a lost connection with another process. Is that the case or is it also vulnerable to corruption if another process is reading or writing to it when terminated?

Comment: From a quick glance through the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/multiprocessing/managers.py) I don't think any cleanup is done, but I'm willing to be proven wrong.